# Is it possible to send a POST request from within an Outlook email?

Tags: post, outlook, request

I would like to send a POST request to a server, I don't want to use GET because the sent message could potentially get very long. I was thinking about using javascript and jquery, but I believe most clients have javascript turned off. Is there another way to send a Post request from within an email?

Yea, I've been unable to use javascript, but does anyone else know of a way to make a post request within an outlook mail message?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Probably not. Most javascript is disabled in emails for security purposes so I highly doubt you'll be able to use any server side code via a supported email client like Outlook. I could be wrong though...

Comment: I was hoping someone else would be able to find a solution, but I guess not. =(

Answer (score 0):

How about using a form with hidden inputs for your parameters